# Tensorflow Object Detection API transfer learning not starting

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection

I am trying to do transfer learning on some custom dataset, using Tensorflow Object Detection API.

When launching the training command, training is never starting and the script seems to be running forever. Here is some output:

```
WARNING:tensorflow:From /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/slim/python/slim/learning.py:736: __init__ (from tensorflow.python.training.supervisor) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Please switch to tf.train.MonitoredTrainingSession
INFO:tensorflow:Restoring parameters from /Users/clementjoudet/Desktop/dev/teeth/models/transfer/ssd_mobilenet_v2_coco_2018_03_29/model.ckpt
INFO:tensorflow:Restoring parameters from /Users/clementjoudet/Desktop/dev/teeth/models/transfer/ssd_mobilenet_v2_coco_2018_03_29/model.ckpt
INFO:tensorflow:Starting Session.
INFO:tensorflow:Starting Session.
INFO:tensorflow:Saving checkpoint to path /Users/clementjoudet/Desktop/dev/teeth/models/transfer/train/model.ckpt
INFO:tensorflow:Saving checkpoint to path /Users/clementjoudet/Desktop/dev/teeth/models/transfer/train/model.ckpt
INFO:tensorflow:Starting Queues.
INFO:tensorflow:Starting Queues.
INFO:tensorflow:global_step/sec: 0
INFO:tensorflow:global_step/sec: 0
INFO:tensorflow:global_step/sec: 0
INFO:tensorflow:global_step/sec: 0
INFO:tensorflow:global_step/sec: 0
INFO:tensorflow:global_step/sec: 0
INFO:tensorflow:global_step/sec: 0
INFO:tensorflow:global_step/sec: 0
```

I tried changing Tensorflow versions, pulling from the Models repo, and using different models (Fastrcnn, SSD_mobilenet), but it is always the same.

I am using the models from https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/detection_model_zoo.md

And the config files with the same name from https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/object_detection/samples/configs

The only things I am changing in the config files are:

- number of classes (my dataset has fewer classes)
- fine_tune_checkpoint path
- input paths for train and eval records + label map path

Note: When I start the training without fine_tune_checkpoint, the training works fine. It is when trying to import a model from the tensorflow zoo that it doesn't work

Here is my folder tree:

```
├── coco.config
├── eval
├── ssd_mobilenet_v2_coco_2018_03_29
│   ├── checkpoint
│   ├── frozen_inference_graph.pb
│   ├── model.ckpt.data-00000-of-00001
│   ├── model.ckpt.index
│   ├── model.ckpt.meta
│   ├── pipeline.config
│   └── saved_model
│       ├── saved_model.pb
│       └── variables
└── train
```

Comment: Which python version are you using?

Comment: I tried both 2.7.14 and 3.6.5. Tensorflow version: 1.5.1

Comment: Tensorflow Version 1.7 with Python 3.6.5 worked for me

Comment: Is the record file generation alright?

Comment: Yes because when I start training from scratch it works

Comment: Is from_detection_checkpoint set to true? Some of the default configs have it as false but if you're training from the model zoo, it should be true.